# How do I get Dr. Domsky?

Tags: full-of-stars

I could use a hand. I need to upgrade to level 3, and need my Dr. Domsky.

I know he is in the pirates' hands. I tried to buy slaves with 5, 10, or 40 idiums several times already, but still fail to get the doctor.

Could any one tell me how to get him?

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per Frank's comment

Answer (score 0):

First go to the slave destination. There you'll learn that he's been sold to pirates. Then go to Tortuga and you will learn where they shipped him.

Answer (score 0):

First, go to the distress signal from New Tokyo. Then, go to the slave destination. There you will be told that Domsky was sold to pirates. From there you go to QCOS. After that, go to Tortuga Station and dock. The pirare will ask you why you're there. Answer "slaves", then ask for Doctor Domsky. You can either threaten the pirate or buy the navkey from him. That unlocks a way to Domsky's Location. Domsky is located on a dark station. You'll ask where he is and get the answer "The Meatshop". You go there, and you see Domsky. You can either put a guild trip on him with leadership points or bribe him with 10 crystals.

Congratulations, doctor Domsky is now part of your crew.

Get through the Heaven's gate to bring him to Blue Sector.